# concatenation of string & integer NAMES within functions (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, concatenation

This is the first posting I've done to this forum.

I have these strings, integers, and filenames declared early on...

```
linefeed='\n'

consonantFileHeader='Consonants found in the infile:'
vowelFileHeader='Vowels found in the infile:'

qConsonant=0
qVowel=0
ConsonantFile=open(path/tothe/file/chapters/Consonants.txt,'w+')
VowelFile=open(path/tothe/file/chapters/Vowels.txt,'w+')
```

the program reads in unicode glyphs one by one, and assigns each a 'type'.

```
if glyph='A': 
   type='VOWEL'
elif glyph='B':
   type='CONSONANT'
    ... etc...
```

later on, we want to add to a running count of each 'type' and write a record to a file that shows all the occurrences of each 'type'. It's routine code, that we don't want cluttering up our `main` function, so we call another function to do it....

```
if  type == 'CONSONANT':
    tabulateCONSONANT(glyph)
elif type == 'VOWEL':
    tabulateVOWEL(glyph)
```

at this point, two different `types` - two different functions. here they are...

```
## ------------------------------------------------------------
def tabulateCONSONANT(glyph):
    qConsonant=qConsonant+1   # bump up a counter
    if  qConsonant = 1        # on 1 write header to output
        ConsonantFile.write(consonantFileHeader)  
    ConsonantFile.write(glyph+linefeed) # write data after    
    return ;
## ------------------------------------------------------------
def tabulateVOWEL(glyph):
    qVowel=qVowel+1  # bump up counter
   if  qVowel = 1
        VowelFile.write(vowelFileHeader) # on 1, write header 
    VowelFile.write(glyph+linefeed)      # write data after
    return ;
```

fine and dandy, but this seems really redundant to me. even though only the actual NAMES of the values change, I have to call a different function for each type!

Is there any way write a single function that wherein we can concatenate the actual ITEM NAMES to do something like the following...?

```
if  type == 'CONSONANT':
    tabulateANYTHING(glyph,'Consonant')
elif type == 'VOWEL': 
    tabulateANYTHING(glyph,'Vowel')

## ------------------------------------------------------------
def tabulateANYTHING(glyph,TYPE):
# concatenate 'q'with 'TYPE' to reference 'qVowel'
    qTYPE=qTYPE+1  
    if  qTYPE = 1
# concatenate 'TYPE' with part of the filename > 'VowelFile'
    TYPEFile.write(TYPEFileHeader)  
    TYPEFile.write(glyph+linefeed)  # again,concatenation...
    return ;
```

if you don't know what the heck I'm trying to do here, let me know and I'll try to make it clearer...

Comment: Suggestion: In the future, consider following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `dict` or a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then inside `tabulateANYTHING` increment the value that has the key that matches `TYPE`

For example, if your dict is named `quantities`:
`quantities[TYPE]+=1`

For the files, create a `dict` of files and write to the one that has the key that matches `TYPE`.
Same thing for the file headers.